# How to initialize attributes in widget class callable?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a custom toggle button (colored rectangle), when i press the button it show a border, if press again hide it.

How i can pass argument to this widget?

```
class ColorSwatch(ToggleButtonBehavior, Widget):

    # Color Button
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ColorSwatch, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #Defaults
        self.up_border_color = self.border_color
        self.down_border_color = self.background_color
        self.border_color = self.down_border_color

    def on_state(self, widget, value):
        if value == 'down':
            # On checked show border
            self.border_color = self.up_border_color
        else:
            # On checked hide border
            self.border_color = self.down_border_color
```

If i run this

```
ColorSwatch(
            border_color=(1,1,1,1),
            border_size=10,
            background_color=(.32, 0.22, 0.55, 1),
        )
```

i get the following error

```
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add properties of `border_color`, `border_size`, and `background_color` to your `ColorSwatch`:

```
class ColorSwatch(ToggleButtonBehavior, Widget):
    border_size = NumericProperty(0)
    border_color = ListProperty([])
    background_color = ListProperty([])
```